# What does '今よ' mean?

Tags: meaning

What does 'よ' do when placed after a single noun like '今'?

> 今よ

Would it be considered a question, like "Now?" ?

Comment: Is there any additional context?  Is it part of a sentence, or is that the whole thing?

Comment: I think it means *Now*.

Comment: @snailboat I found it by itself. Unfortunately no context..

Comment: Context (perhaps we should say situation or circumstances) is more than the preceding and following sentence - where did you find it?

Comment: @blutorange On a post-it, left on a table in a library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the meaning, it means just what よ always does as a sentence-final particle... it emphasizes the sentence is intended to convey information to the listener.

More important though is the fact that it is a sentence-final particle.

For some reason, the interjection `Now!`, said when you want someone to take a (prearranged, mutually agreed) action right at that moment, doesn't seem to work in Japanese with just the noun `今`. It needs to be a sentence like `今だ` ("[It, the time to act] is now"). A sentence-final particle achieves that.

The use of `よ` here in `今よ` is another way to make `今` into a sentence, and which compared to `今だ` or `今だよ` has more of a feminine feel due to the dropping of `だ`.

(Here we start getting into role language and the difference in usage of `だ` and `よ` between genders in real life and fiction.)

> [Wiktionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%88#.E5.8A.A9.E8.A9.9E):
>   口語の終助詞。主体の意志・知識を主張する。**だ あるいは です を省略してよを付けるのは、女性に使われる** が、現在では少ない *(at least in real life --Hyper)*。
>
> - もうやめようよ。
> - それは私のものよ。(女性的。現在では男女ともに「それは私のものだよ。」)

Answer (score 5):

> What does 'よ' do when placed after a ***single noun*** like '今'?

There is a usage which answers this question that is really different than the answer you were probably expecting (and certainly this example), but I will answer it anyway.

It is the `呼び掛け` usage, meant to call someone's/something's attention to what you're saying.  It translates to "Oh (you) 〜", or "Hey 〜" and usually accompanies a request or command

> - 神様**よ**、私の願いをかなえたまえ！　→　O God, please answer my prayer!
> - 迫害された人々**よ**、立ち上がって戦おう！　→　(Hey) you oppressed people, stand up and fight!
> - 雲**よ**、雨を降らせ！　→　(Hey/O) Clouds, make it rain!
> - 田中君**よ**、手をかしてくれないか　→　Hey Tanaka, help me out will ya?

Like I said, this doesn't relate to your example of `今よ`, but it applies to the way you worded the question.

Comment: Actually in English the vocative particle is usually spelled as just uppercase 'O': "O God", "O ye of little faith" etc.

Answer (score 3):

「今よ」 is not a question.
It's a female way of saying "Now!"