# What is the meaning of よ in the phrase 雨よ雪に変わってくれ

Tags: usage

Read this phrase in a blog. I think the basic meaning of the phrase 雨よ雪に変わってくれ is "The rain is changing into snow."
But I don't understand the usage of よ in this case. Is it a particle?
Or is it a typo?

Comment: See also: [How to invoke God/spirits in Japanese](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3241/3437).

Comment: Related:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12401/78

Comment: You are talking to the rain.  The よ is NOT a typo.

Comment: I always see it in the phrase 「友よ」. Great question, I wondered this myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a vocative particle, like the English vocative *"O"* in the following example:

> *O Rain!  Please change into snow!*

It sounds poetic or literary.

It's defined as 係助詞「よ」 in 集英社国語辞典:

> 係助詞。**相手への呼びかけ**。「泣くな妹**よ**、妹**よ**泣くな」「風**よ**伝えよ、かの人に」「モズ**よ**、寒いと鳴くでねえ」

I bolded the meaning, which is basically vocative.